# How to use "Run Keywork If" and "Get Element Attribute" in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I am checking if my element exists, it it does then get "@class" attribute if that element. I am not sure How to do this.

Here is my code

```
${disabled}=|Set Variable|NONE
${elementPresent}| Is Element Present| ${LOCATOR}
Run Keyword If|"${elementPresent}" == "True"|${disabled}=|Get Element Attribute ${LOCATOR}@class
```

Here it gives me error that "NONE" is not keyword. Can someone help me here.

Comment: is this literally your code? You don't have enough whitespace surrounding your pipes.

Comment: no that was not my code, more of a sudo code

Answer (score 3):

Quick attempt so have a play until I get back online, I think this happens when it's not hitting your check.  The below is how I'd clean it up:

```
${disabled}=    {FALSE}
${elementPresent}| Is Element Present| ${LOCATOR}
${disabled}=    Run Keyword If|${elementPresent}|Get Element Attribute ${LOCATOR}@class
```

Let me know what happens.  I'm guessing elementPresent will contain only true or false?

Ah sorry I just read further, so basically your NONE is screwing things up.  I would change the value as above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. It was not working due to some error.

```
${disabled}=|Run Keyword If|"${elementPresent}" == "True"|Get Element Attribute |${LOCATOR}@class
```

Comment: Please accept the answer in that case.  Regarding "${elementPresent}" == "True", this is redundant.  as I gave in my example you can just do 

Run Keyword If  |  ${elementPresent}

This essentially means, run if true.  Following my example you default it to false instead of having NONE

Comment: I believe your error is that you had the target of your assignment (${disabled}) after Run Keyword If. The target must always precede the first keyword on the line. You should accept @schicky's answer.